# how should i be able to run validation on my code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

this is my controller

```
public function perengkingan(Request $request)
{
    $kriteriaPenilaian = Profilbidangkajian::all();
    foreach ($kriteriaPenilaian as $key => $value) {
        $nilai[$value->matakuliah->nama] = 'required';
    }
    
    
    $validated = $request->validate($nilai);
    dd($validated);
}
```

i've dd(validated); for check my data but my code nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Validate the request like this,

```
public function perengkingan(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => ['required', '...'],
    ]);
}

dd($validator->validated());
```

Check the original reference https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators